# Windows couldn't connect to Profsvc service

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

I tried loging into windows and it throws me this error. This happens for my Visitor account. For admin account it just goes into 'Preparing Desktop' for hours. So i generally restart after that.

I tried some solutions I found. None worked. 
Tried logging into safe mode. Same problem.

What else can i do other than a fresh install? I can't also do a system restore.

Comment: What solutions did you find that you tried? Why can you not do a system restore (which you can do from recovery media)? How long has this been happening? Do you know what happened that cause this to start happening?

Comment: Everywhere it showed to login to safe mode, which is not working for me. Also it said about creating administrator profile using cmd, which also did not work. System restore from a revovery media seems to be not working. No system restore points found. This suddenly popped up a few days ago. I shit down my laptop one evening, tried opening it at night, couldn't do it.